# Sending Mysql $body as table data not attachment

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I need to send data from mysql db via email. I am using php mailer  as mail sender. I found solutions where I can send it as attachment but not as  Formated body. When I do get_file_contents 'displaywebpage.php' reads out ony Html formating and all php comes out as strings. Not calling db or anything. When I check in browser on myserver/displaywebpage.php works perfect but when emailing it doesnt work.

Here is mailsend.php

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  
$body = file_get_contents('displaywebpage.php');


try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             
$mail->Username = 'xx@gmail.com';                
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;                                   

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('xx@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('to_xy@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     
// $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');              
$mail->addReplyTo('xx', 'Mailer');
// $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//  $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//Attachments
// $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//  $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

and here is displaywebpage.php

```
 <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass");
 if(!$con){
       die("Database Connection failed".mysqli_error());
}else{
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($con,'test2');
     if(!$db_select){
           die("Database selection failed".mysqli_error());
}else{

   }
}

 $records = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test2 ORDER by field2");



?>

<!-- This piece of PHP code defines the structure of the html table -->

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
    <title> web report </title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <table width="500" border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing='1'>

       <tr bgcolor="#2ECCFA">
                 <th> user</th>
                 <th>Device</th>
                 <th>Last Contact</th>
       </tr>

<!-- We use while loop to fetch data and display rows of date on html table -->

<?php

 while ($course = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

       print "<tr>";
           print "<td>".$course['user']."</td>";
           print "<td>".$course['Device_ID']."</td>";
           print "<td>".$course['Last_Contact']."</td>";
       print "</tr>";

 }
?>
        </table>

   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`include` the file and capture its output using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
include 'displaywebpage.php';
$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Glad that worked - Please mark this answer as your preferred answer - click the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

*file_get_content* get all the contents in a file but **will not execute the file** !

To solve your problem you have two options (if you want to keep your logic) :

1. Use Ajax to call the displaywebpage.php and echo back the contents (which give you the executed code)
2. get the contents of the displaywebpage.php using *file_get_content* and then run your PHP code inside mailsend.php and then replace your strings with contents that you already got.

In case if you want to use the second option (which I think should be easier for you), you should remove all the PHP codes from displaywebpage.php and add them to the mailsend.php and using *str_replace* replace your string to your html :

```
$body = '<tr>
 <td>[user]</td>
 <td>[Device_ID]</td>
 <td>[Last_Contact]</td>
</tr>'; // this is inside your displaywebpage.php which you got using *file_get_content*


$user = $course['user'];
$device_id = $course['Device_ID'];
$last_content = $course['Last_Contact'];

$body .= str_replace ('[user]', $user, $body);
$body .= str_replace ('[Device_ID]', $device_id, $body);
$body .= str_replace ('[Last_Contact]', $last_content, $body);
```